# JdbcTemplate update query giving AssertionError ?

Tags: java, powermock

I am writing test cases for DAO class and I am using JDBC template and Power mock .IN dao method i am calling two times jdbctemplate method then i am getting some error.
Please find below code

```
JdbcTemplate jt = createStrictMock(JdbcTemplate.class);
String sql = "select SQN_ALERTS_CCH_JOB_ID.NEXTVAL from DUAL";
String sqlInsert = "insert into C_ALERTS_CCH_JOB (MSG_ID, MESSAGE, ACTION, ACTION_TM, ERR_DESC, SEQ_NO)"
                        + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
EasyMock.expect(jt.queryForLong(sql)).andReturn(529340l).times(1);
EasyMock.expect(jt.update(sqlInsert, parameters)).andReturn(1).times(1);
PowerMock.replay(jt);
PowerMock.replayAll();
Object[] parameters = new Object[6];
parameters[0] = jt.queryForLong(sql);
jt.update(sql, parameters);
```

then i am getting below error

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: 
Unexpected method call JdbcTemplate.update("insert into C_ALERTS_CCH_JOB (MSG_ID, MESSAGE, ACTION, ACTION_TM,
ERR_DESC, SEQ_NO) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", [null, null, null, 2015-05-11 19:49:29.585, null, 529340]):
JdbcTemplate.queryForLong("select SQN_ALERTS_CCH_JOB_ID.NEXTVAL from DUAL"): expected: 1, actual: 1
JdbcTemplate.update("insert into C_ALERTS_CCH_JOB (MSG_ID, MESSAGE, ACTION, ACTION_TM, ERR_DESC, SEQ_NO) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", [null, null, null, 2015-05-11 19:49:29.585, null, 529340]): expected: 1, actual: 0
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6e3c18ec.update(<generated>)
```

Why ?

Comment: Move your parameter higher berfore your easymock.expect() statements

Answer (score 0):

Your second mock is returning 0 when it was expecting 1... Hence the assertion error

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i am not bale to understand how to resolve this problem please elaborate.